# Why is this character expression an integer?

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory

Let $\gamma$ be an $n$-dimensional complex representation of a finite group $G$ with character $\chi$ and let $e=c_0, c_1, ..., c_{\ell}$ be a set of conjugacy class representatives for $G$.  In the case where $\gamma$ is faithful, I recently obtained the formula $$ \frac{1}{|G|} \prod_{i=1}^{\ell} (n-\chi(c_i))$$ as the size of a certain abelian group associated with $\gamma$ (see Theorem 3 in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.00798) if interested).  In particular, this implies that this quantity is always an integer (if $\gamma$ is not faithful, then the product is 0).

Is there a nice way to see that this is an integer just using basic character theory?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, this is an observation of H. Blichfeldt ( I think J-P. Serre also attributes it to Minkowski), which has been rediscovered many times over the years. Letting $1$ denote the trivial character, note that 
$\theta = \prod_{i = 1}^{\ell} ( \chi - \chi(c_{i})1) $ is an algebraic integer combination of characters of $G$, and also vanishes everywhere on $G$ except the identity, where its value is $\prod_{i = 1}^{\ell} ( n - \chi(c_{i})) .$  Hence $\theta$ is an algebraic integer multiple of the regular character of $G$, and 
$\langle \theta,1 \rangle = \frac{1}{|G|}\prod_{i = 1}^{\ell} ( n - \chi(c_{i})) $
is an algebraic integer ( which is easily seen to be rational by Galois theory, hence is a rational integer).

(Edit: In fact, it is only necessary to take the distinct values of $\chi(c_{i})$ without repetition in the product which is what Blichfeldt did).

Comment: do you know a reference for Blichfeldt's observation?

Comment: I think is is "A Theorem concerning the invariants of linear homogeneous groups with some applications to substitution groups", Trans AMS 5 (1904),4,461-466. I think it is reviewed as MR 1500684. Also relevant is a paper of D. Chillag which is reviewed as MR238502.